# Executing 2 batch scripts consecutively

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have 2 batch scripts:

sleep1.bat

```
echo sleep 4 seconds
timeout /t 4
exit
```

sleep2.bat

```
echo sleep 3 seconds
timeout /t 3
exit
```

Is it possible to execute `sleep1.bat` and `sleep2.bat` consecutively so that the program can sleep for a total of 7 seconds?

sleepMain.bat

```
call sleep1.bat
call sleep2.bat
pause
```

`SleepMain.bat` fails to do what I want. It only executes `slee1.bat`, because `sleep1.bat` contains `exit`.

`sleep1.bat` and `sleep2.bat` are written by others, I wish I don't have to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me under Windows 10:

```
cmd /c sleep1.bat
cmd /c sleep2.bat
pause
```

It works by launching the batch scripts in a separate command instance. The output looks like this:

```
D:\workspace\deleteme>sleepMain.bat

D:\workspace\deleteme>cmd /c sleep1.bat

D:\workspace\deleteme>echo sleep 4 seconds
sleep 4 seconds

D:\workspace\deleteme>timeout /t 4

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

D:\workspace\deleteme>exit

D:\workspace\deleteme>cmd /c sleep2.bat

D:\workspace\deleteme>echo sleep 3 seconds
sleep 3 seconds

D:\workspace\deleteme>timeout /t 3

Waiting for 0 seconds, press a key to continue ...

D:\workspace\deleteme>exit

D:\workspace\deleteme>pause
Press any key to continue . . .

D:\workspace\deleteme>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just what I want :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `exit` will definitely exits, but it exit the console instead of the current batch script. 
To prevent that happen, use `exit /b`.
**Tips:**

> 1. Use `exit` only in the **main** script.
> 2. If you're just doing some simple thing in *sleep1.bat*, you can choose to not to add an `exit /b` command. 
>    Try it yourself : *1.bat* - `set "you=you"`, *2.bat* - `set "you=you" & exit /b`
>      In *3.bat*, try either `call 1.bat & echo %you%` or `call 2.bat & echo %you%`, you will still get `you` as the output. This mean either script with `exit /b` or none still can access the variables in the previous called batch script. (Safe to try with simple script)

Answer (score 1):

1. As an altervative way to terminate execution of a batch script without exiting the current `cmd` instance, you do not need to put anything in a straight-forward script like yours (where one command is just run after the other, no execution branches, no if clauses, no loop structures). To tell the script explicitly to quit execution, you can also use `goto :EOF`. The `:EOF` is an implicit label that points to the end of the script (type `goto /?` in the command prompt for more details). This works only when command extensions are enabled, which is the case as per default (see `cmd /?` for that). To use this method without extension, just define the label `:EOF` by writing it as the very last line.
2. Your two scripts will not last 4 + 3 = 7 seconds, but something between 6 and 7 seconds actually. This is because the `timeout` command returns at certain second multiples, so the very first one may be shorter (0 s > actual delay time >= 1 s). The wait time can even be interrupted by keyboard interaction in your script; to prevent that, add the `/NOBREAK` option (see `timeout /?` for help). To really wait for 4 seconds for example, state `> nul ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5`; the given IP address means "home", so the host itself, therefore it is always valid; the `5` defines the number of `ping` attempts, so there are `4` one-second intervals in between; `> nul` redirects the display output to the `nul` device, meaning that nothing is displayed.